# Problems with IDENTITY_INSERT Set to OFF? :-/

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, identity

I'm trying to insert order details into my DB, and it keeps saying:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Orders' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

All I am trying to do is simply insert the users UserId into the UserId column, by using `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` - Why is this not working?

I have:

```
dbase.Execute("INSERT INTO Orders 
                 (UserId, OrderId, Status) 
               VALUES 
                 (@0, @1, @2)", 
               WebSecurity.CurrentUserId, 
               Session["OSFOID"], 
               "Confirmed");`
```

So, as you can see, it's pretty simple. But, why won't it work?

My table definition is:

[image: Table Definition]

Comment: The system does allow repeat customers. The orders table is only used for temporarily storing information.

Comment: Sorry, this data model isn't making a lot of sense to me...

Comment: This data model is based on a clients existing Access Database he has. I'm sorry it doesn't make any sense, and I know it needs to be changed, but that's not something he's willing to change right now, as he is "too busy" with other work stuff.

Comment: Actually, since I'm bored as hell most days, I think I might see about changing it myself if he'll let me.

Comment: @OMG - No need to be sorry. :) I appreciate all the help you've given me over the months

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unless you *enable* the ability to do identity-insert (by setting identity-insert ***on*** for that table), you are NOT ALLOWED to touch that column - the database owns it.

Either enable identity insert ***briefly***, or: don't try to insert the UserId (let the DB create a new id).

As per books online, [`SET IDENTITY_INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188059.aspx):

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Orders ON
INSERT INTO Orders (UserId, OrderId, Status) VALUES (@0, @1, @2)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Orders OFF
```

More likely, though: if this is the `Orders` table, should the identity not be on `OrderId` ? You'd still have the same problem since you are trying to control the `OrderId`, of course.

Comment: I understand that. But, I also have another table with the same definition. And I can insert into that no problems.

Comment: I'm not creating a new id. I am inserting an existing one.

Comment: @jase - No, you don't.  It is obviously not the same definition, otherwise you would get the same error.  There must be a difference.

Comment: @jase - as far as *that table* is concerned, it doesn't care whether the number exists somewhere else. Re "another table with the same definition" - then *either* that table doesn't have the `IDENTITY`, or you already have `IDENTITY_INSERT` enabled on that table.

Comment: @jase - If you are inserting an existing ID, then the column should not be defined as an Identity field.  An Identity field auto-generates it's ID and does not (normally) allow insertion.

Answer (score 3):

Generally you would not want to insert an integer into a primary key column. You would usually set the column's "Identity" flag to true only where you wanted to have SQL Server set an auto-incrementing integer into this column on insert.

As with Marc Gravell's answer, you can enable identity insert using

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [ database. [ owner. ] ] { table } { ON | OFF }
```

But doing this in regular application code is really unhealthy -- you'll end up with concurrency issues and quite likely duplicate identities. Better, don't insert the Order's ID -- let the DB do it for you automatically, and then simply query for the new ID using `@@IDENTITY` (or better, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`).

If for some reason you definitely need to store the user's session id, make this a separate column on the order table, or better still, on a separate User table, with the UserId being a foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want the UserID to be an Identity, and I also do not think you want the UserID to be the primary key either.  More than likely, you want the OrderID to be the primary key, or at best shared primary key with the userid and orderid.

Answer (score 1):

In your table's definition set `Is Identity?` as `False`, with out setting that you cant insert a value manually to the `UserID`

Comment: you *can*, and the error message already tells you *how*... changing the `IDENTITY` is not to be taken lightly - of course it is entirely possible it is *wrong* at the moment (but that is different to blindly removing it)

Answer (score 1):

You have set **IS Identity to YES** that's why now you cant insert value for this column DB will automatically insert it by incrementing values..

And the thing i am seeing you set UserId as the primary key of the table which is wrong Order OoderID should be the primary key of the column.

Set UserID IsIdentify to false
and OrderID IsEdentitfy to yes and made it primary key column.

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly I found that when I created a table using a "Select.....Into [new table] from [tables containing data]" I subsequently could not Insert new records, getting the Insert_Identity set to off message.
I got around this by deleting the table then using a Create Table script to rebuild it and now have no problems inserting as many new IDs as needed